# Obter String do arquivo strings.xml

Tags: java, android

Estou tentado recuperar uma `String` do arquivo `strings.xml` para esta variável `SQL_CID`.

```
<string name="insert_cid">"
    INTO `CID` (`COD_CID`, `NOME_CID`, `CODIGO_CID`) VALUES(1, 'CÓLERA DEVIDA A VIBRIO CHOLERAE 01, BIÓTIPO CHOLERAE', 'A000'),(2, 'CÓLERA DEVIDA A VIBRIO CHOLERAE 01, BIÓTIPO EL TOR', 'A001'),(3, 'CÓLERA NÃO ESPECIFICADA', 'A009'),(4, 'FEBRE TIFÓIDE', 'A010'),(5, 'FEBRE PARATIFÓIDE A', 'A011')
</string>
```

JAVA:

```
String SQL_CID = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.insert_cid);
db.execSQL(SQL_CID);
```

Mas esta dando erro.

Comment: posta o erro que ocorre por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve usar:

- numa Activity ou Service

  ```
  String SQL_CID = getString(R.string.insert_cid);
  ```
- em outro local, necessita de ter um Context

  ```
  String SQL_CID = myContext.getString(R.string.insert_cid);
  ```

`Resources.getSystem().getString()` só acede a recursos do sistema, não acede a recursos da aplicação como é o caso.

Comment: eu tento usar o getString() mas esta com esse erro 
non-static method getclass() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: O método `getString()` é um método de instância, tem de ter um objecto Context para o poder utilizar. Se o código não estiver numa Activity tem de passar um Context(a Activity por exemplo) para ele e depois usar `String SQL_CID = myContext.getString(R.string.insert_cid);`

Comment: muito Obrigado pela explicação ajudou bastante. ainda estou com algum problema mas muito obrigado